# i tried to display data to DropDownButton from rest api using flutter and json data but it didnt work

Tags: json, api, flutter

**my code:**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:shaal/module/home.dart';
    import 'package:shaal/controlers/databasehelper.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:shaal/module/showdata.dart';

    class AddData extends StatefulWidget{

      AddData({Key key , this.title}) : super(key : key);
      final String title;

      @override
      AddDataState  createState() => AddDataState();

    }

    class AddDataState extends State<AddData> {

      List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
      String _error;

      DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper();


      final TextEditingController _nameController = new TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController _priceController = new TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController _descriptionController = new TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController _quantityController = new TextEditingController();

      /*
      "currency_id": "1",
      "unit_id": "1",
      "case_id": "1",
      "price": "4",
      "name": "bysicle",
      "description": "it is new ",
      "quantity": "5",
      "country_id": "1",
      "category_id": "1"
    */

      String _mySelection;

      List country_data = List();

      String countryid;

      Future<String> country() async {
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

        final key = 'session_id';
        final value = prefs.get(key ) ?? 0;

        var res = await http.get(
            Uri.encodeFull("http://husam.from-ar.com/api/api-ad/en/1"),
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json",
                     "Authorization" : "$value",
            }); //if you have any auth key place here...properly..
        var resBody = await json.decode(res.body);

        setState(()  {
          country_data =  resBody;

        });

        return "Sucess";
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        this.country();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Add Product',
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                 child: Container(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                   child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                     Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                       children:
                       <Widget>[
                         IconButton(
                           onPressed: () {
                             Navigator.pop(context);
                           },
                           icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                           iconSize: 30,
                           color: Colors.red[300],
                         ),
                       ],),
                     SizedBox(height: 30,),
                     SizedBox(
                       width: 400,
                       child: Card(
                         child: Container(
                           padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                           child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(height: 9,),
                             TextField(
                               controller: _nameController,
                               obscureText: false,
                               autofocus: true,
                               cursorColor: Colors.black,
                               decoration: InputDecoration(
                                 labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                     color: Colors.black54
                                 ),
                                 border: InputBorder.none,
                                 focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(

                                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                                 ),
                                 icon: Icon(Icons.title,
                                   color: Colors.black45,

                                 ),


                                 labelText: 'Name',

                               ),
                             ),
                             SizedBox(height: 9,),
                             TextField(

                               obscureText: false,
                               cursorColor: Colors.black,
                               controller: _descriptionController,
                               decoration: InputDecoration(
                                 border: InputBorder.none,
                                 labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                     color: Colors.black54
                                 ),

                                 focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                                 ),

                                 icon: Icon(Icons.description,
                                   color: Colors.black45,

                                 ),


                                 labelText: 'description',

                               ),
                             ),
                             SizedBox(height: 9,),

                             TextField(

                               obscureText: false,
                               cursorColor: Colors.black,
                               controller: _quantityController,
                               decoration: InputDecoration(
                                 border: InputBorder.none,
                                 labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                     color: Colors.black54
                                 ),

                                 focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                                 ),

                                 icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_hide,
                                   color: Colors.black45,

                                 ),


                                 labelText: 'quantity',

                               ),
                             ),
                            SizedBox(height: 9,),
                             TextField(

                               controller: _priceController,

                               cursorColor: Colors.black,
                               decoration: InputDecoration(
                                 border: InputBorder.none,
                                 labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                     color: Colors.black54
                                 ),

                                 focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                                 ),

                                 icon: Icon(Icons.equalizer,
                                   color: Colors.black45,

                                 ),


                                 labelText: 'price',

                               ),
                             ),
                           ],
                           ),),

                       ),

                     ),

                   Column(
                     children: <Widget>[
    DecoratedBox(
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                           child: Padding(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 0, 0),
                             //Why you have used Stack ??????
                             //B'coz it make clickable to whole decorated Box!!!! as you can click anywhere for dropdown !!!
                             child: Stack(
                               children: <Widget>[

    //Country Text
                                 Text(
                                   "Country:  ",

                                   style: TextStyle(
                                     fontSize: 13.0,
                                   ),
                                 ),

    //Dropdown that has no loine beneath

                                 DropdownButtonHideUnderline(

                                   child:

    //starting the dropdown
                                   DropdownButton(
                                     items: country_data.map((item) {

                                       return new DropdownMenuItem(

                                           child: new Text(
                                             item['countries']['name'],    //Names that the api dropdown contains
                                             style: TextStyle(
                                               fontSize: 13.0,
                                             ),
                                           ),
                                           value: item['countries']['id'].toString()


                                          //e.g   India (Name)    and   its   ID (55fgf5f6frf56f) somethimg like that....
                                       );
                                     }).toList(),

                                     onChanged: (String newVal)  {
                                       setState(() {
                                        countryid = newVal;
                                         print(countryid.toString());
                                       });
                                     },

                                     value: countryid,           
                                   ),


                                 )
                               ],
                             ),
                           )),
                     ],
                   ),



                     Center(child: Text('Error: $_error')),
                     RaisedButton(
                       child: Text("Pick images"),
                       onPressed: loadAssets,
                     ),
                     Expanded(
                       child: buildGridView(),
                     ),










                     Container(
                       height: 50,
                       child: new RaisedButton(
                         onPressed: () {
                           databaseHelper.addData(_descriptionController.text.trim(),
                               _quantityController.text.trim(),
                               _nameController.text.trim(),
                               _priceController.text.trim());
                           Navigator.of(context).push(
                               new MaterialPageRoute(
                                 builder: (BuildContext context) => new Dashboard(),
                               )
                           );
                         },
                         color: Colors.red,
                         child: new Text(
                           'Add ad',
                           style: new TextStyle(
                               color: Colors.white,
                               backgroundColor: Colors.red),),
                       ),
                     ),


                   ],
                   ),
                 ),
              )

                ],),

              ),
            ),

          ),
        );














      }












      Widget buildGridView() {
        if (images != null)
          return GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
              Asset asset = images[index];
              return AssetThumb(
                asset: asset,
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
              );
            }),
          );
        else
          return Container(color: Colors.white);
      }


      Future<void> loadAssets() async {
        setState(() {
          images = List<Asset>();
        });

        List<Asset> resultList;
        String error;



        try {
          resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
            maxImages: 6,
          );
        } on Exception catch (e) {
          error = e.toString();
        }

        // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
        // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
        // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
        if (!mounted) return;

        setState(() {
          images = resultList;
          if (error == null) _error = 'No Error Dectected';
        });
      }











    }
```

**my json data**

```
{
    "products": [],
    "productStatus": [
        {
            "name": "OLD",
            "id": 1
        }
    ],
    "countries": [
        {
            "name": "Turkey",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Syria",
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "currencies": [
        {
            "name": "DOLLAR",
            "id": 1
        }
    ],
    "units": [
        {
            "name": "KG",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "liter",
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "addresses": []
}
```

**i hided my rest api**

> quote i want to display data in DropDownButton but its not work 
>   my code working without errors.
>   my json data its multiple object i called him and i seed my data in debugger but the data didnt going inside DropDownButton why i didnt know because i didnt see any error.

Comment: hey osama, please edit your question in formatted manner so that community can answer your question break you code into different files and explain it fully what are you doing and what are your expectations and also if you can remove unnecessary code that is not useful to your problem that would be great. I surely try to answer this questions if you do as above. Thanks

Comment: ok i will edite it

Comment: if i uploaded it yo github can you help me?

Comment: I can look into

Comment: its my new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62049329/i-want-to-display-data-in-dropdownbutton-from-rest-api-using-flutter